# Whitescreen after splashscreen in some android mobiles - IONIC Cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, splash-screen, android-splashscreen

My mobile application is built by  IONIC Cordova.

We are getting whitescreen after splashscreen in some android mobiles(working fine in most of the device). When whitescreen comes, we are getting below error in console.

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token`

I tried by autohide into false in config.xml and manually hide in appcomponent. But appcomponent constructor itself not triggered.

**Note** : Am getting this issue in random devices only. not in all mobiles.

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As per the error message

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

It might be because of some unknown character in either of your JavaScript files or your HTML/CSS files.

Please check all files and see if they are syntactically correct or not.

If possible please post your complete code as well.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."